# Server configuration with wordpress install

Tags: php, wordpress, ini

I have been struggling with this for 2 weeks now.

I tried so many fixes or solutions that I have researched on forums. I have tried to set different values on my PHP.ini page.

I have tried to debug = true and logged debug errors, but nothing of value shows up..??

Here is the video of the problem:

http://youtu.be/ILkaSyxFaDs

I am sure a have a value that is wrong, but can't nail it down.. ??

[image]

Comment: Any help or comments are very welcomed!!

Comment: It seems like its a common issue when using windows.  This is a workaround that I have found.  Have you attempted to add this to your wp-config.php file? define( 'WP_TEMP_DIR', ABSPATH . 'wp-content/' );

Comment: have you check phpinfo(), is zip enabled?

Comment: You can also check this article as it may be a permission issue.  http://kb.parallels.com/en/115628

Comment: @MichalS Yes, checked phpinfo, and zip is enabled!

Comment: @RobertLee This isn't a windows install. On Apache / Linux

Comment: @RobertLee checked my upload_tmp_dir on phpinfo and found it was No Value. Maybe that is the problem ? I added a screenshot above.

Comment: if the files are installed it's not a permission problem, it's wp issue, no upload temp dir in phpinfo is ok too. have you tired with small&simple plugins?

Comment: yes, i have tried with a fresh install, new theme, old theme, big plugins and small plugins. same thing.

Comment: What you mean by fresh install? Whole wp??

Comment: yes - completely new wordpress install on same server (just dif. directory )

Comment: check your file permission for the `wp-content` folder. try adding `AddType x-mapp-php5 .php` to the top of you htaccess file

Comment: @Mark tried both of those, no dice... thanks for the effort

Comment: Confirm the [File Permissions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions). Also try: [override file permissions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Override_of_default_file_permissions) and [setting the upgrade constants](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_Upgrade_Constants) in `wp-config.php`.

Comment: Could you be a bit more informative, which wp version, or has it done that with different versions so far? Have you tried with a different browser? Do you have adblock plus? Do you control the server locally or is it a hired one? If it isn't local, can you reproduce the problem locally, etc... Also, in principle this should be moved to the wp.stackexchange website.

Comment: Also can you at least verify if the problem is server or client side by analysing the server response (with firebug or anything like that). It's just that as far as I can tell, wp is functioning normally, but you just don't see some message. This might be an ajax problem. If you have access to another wp on which you don't have the problem, look at the browser server communication to see the difference, then inform us exactly what happens.

Comment: @nus I am pretty sure it is server side! Thanks, I will test the "ajax" problem tomorrow

Comment: It seems that fatal error occurs during the installation. Check your error_log or set display_errors to on and error_reporting to E_ALL in your php.ini.

Comment: @Darhazer thanks for the reply. That was actually the first thing I did. Nothing Fatal at all. It is just strange that on the plugins page, it just stops loading after a certain amount of time. ??

Comment: When uploading a plugin, it first gets stored in the PHP's temp folder http://imgur.com/dbn3h94 (first one). If such folder doesn't exist or is deleted, then WP throws an error http://imgur.com/vrkOtM7.

Try to set zlib.output_compression = off
in your php.ini ...

Comment: @Manolis WOW!! I didn't think zlib would have any effect!! But well done!! You got it!

Comment: Welcome :) Will put this into reply to stand out and help others, and receive the bounty if you don't mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to set `zlib.output_compression = off` in the `php.ini`, per the discussion in the OP's question.

*FYI, when uploading a plugin, it first gets stored in the PHP's temp folder (first one):*

[image: Screenshot]

*If such folder doesn't exist or is deleted, then WP throws an error:*

[image: Missing a temporary folder]